# How to reload data after showback()

Tags: codenameone

I have a form that loads multibuttons from an SQLite table.  On that form is an add button which shows another form to add a new record to the table.  The save button on that form saves the record to the table and calls the parent form's showBack() method.  I can't figure out how to get the data to reload from the table so the new record is displayed.  How do I refresh a data set from a database table as part of the form navigation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to re-run the form form construction.

I'm guessing you did something like:

```
MyForm() {
   //... add stuff to my form ...
}
```

Move that code to an `init()` method and before calling `showBack()` just invoke something like `reloadData()`:

```
public void reloadData() {
   removeAll();
   init();
}
```

Comment: Sorry if I'm being dense, but I'm still at the "following the tutorials" knowledge level with Codename One here, although I'm comfortable with Java.  Is there an example in any of the demos or tutorials of what you mean that is more explanatory?

Comment: If you are familiar with Java then this should be pretty close to the way you would do that in Swing. You need to write the logic of updating the form with the new data as the component framework is oblivious of the underlying data. Since this is tied ti the business logic I'm not sure how an example of this will help?

Comment: Got it.  I wasn't extending Form.  I was just doing Form f = new Form().  I think I understand what you mean now so I'll give it a go.